# Jmeter，How to test multiple people login at the same time？

Tags: jmeter

I use Blazemeter to record the script, save the script information, and open it in JMeter.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROt7r.png)
The test result is correct. Then I want to use this script to test multiple people logging in at the same time.
First, I use the CSV data set config to add parameters, and then modify it to a variable in the login interface.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/993G9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRXbB.png)
After running, an error is displayed and the login fails.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSQ9V.jpg)

Comment: What is the problem? Can you explain what's happening in the pictures?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post screenshot of the response also? what is the response code reported? 401 or 5xx>
I see the login details passed to the post body is encoded. Is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see your `${pass}` variable doesn't have any value assigned, unfortunately we cannot help further without seeing your CSV file (at least first 2 lines) so only generic pieces of advice can be provided like:

- check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
- check which JMeter Variables are being generated using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination

If you need comprehensive instructions on setting up the CSV Data Set Config - check out [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) article